# how can i see which optimizations Java makes

Tags: java, performance

I have the following code

```
 public boolean matches(String word) {

     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w$");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(word);
     return m.find();

 }
```

I want to know if the java compiler substitutes the Pattern.compile("\w$") phrase with an object, or creates the object every time the function is called.

How can i find out what java makes to my code?
Is there an eclipse plugin which shows this?

Comment: You could use the debugger to walk through your code and see

Comment: Why would javac do anything with this code? How could it possibly know whether this code is used in one thread or many?

Comment: May you please explain your last comment more? Why is the number of threads important ?

Comment: @David Had java created a single Pattern object to be used each time this function is called, the function would become thread-usafe.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code, it creates the object every time the function is called.

```
public static Pattern compile(String regex) {
    return new Pattern(regex, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler will simply emit an `invokestatic` bytecode instruction against `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile`. And indeed, this method will return a `Pattern` object that your code then has at its disposal.

So what you really want to know is readily available in the source code of `Pattern.compile`. If that method just returns a new `Pattern` object, there will be no reuse with future calls. If you see that the object is being cached, then some reuse will happen.

So have a look at the source code of the Java version that is of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

`compile` method creates new object `Pattern` which is reused later.

From source code:

```
public static Pattern compile(String regex, int flags) {
    return new Pattern(regex, flags);
}
```

Comment: it is reused only if the programmer takes care to reuse it. As far as the Java API is concerned, there is **no reuse** (no caching).

Answer (score 0):

To view the optimizations done by compiler, you can follow like this:

1)Compile your program

2)decompile your program using java decompilers available (can check in google) to generate the source code again

3)compare your source with the decompiled one.

That will give you enough idea...

as decompilers are not so smart (and there's no need either).

While viewing runtime optimizations are much more difficult.

Comment: Decompiler is useless for this job: it will only show that `Pattern.compile` is indeed invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You only know for sure if you have a look at the Java Bytecode generated sine Java has a lot of optimizations build in already.

For Eclipse I know[Bytecode Outline plugin](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/index.html) to show the bytecode directly from eclipse. Maybe you need to search for some resources how to read the bytecolde probably but most of it is kinda easy like object creation or class calls.

Comment: Does this plugin work with eclipse juno? The site says that there is an update site just till eclipse 3.5

Comment: Sorry I do not know since I am not using Eclipse since a long time. I found the plugin in the marketplace http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bytecode-outline#.UYuhvLUqxpg maybe this is working with newer versions. Else search for Bytecode in the marketplace I guess there are plenty of plugins still providing you such a view.